# get the value of the key in an array in php without foreach loop and for loop

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I have an array and I need to change the value of a column but without looping, because it duplicates the results

```
 $job_query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from job j , company c where j.company = c.id')->result_array();

 $companyC = $this->db->query('SELECT j.company ,c.title, c.city, c.logo , c.logo , c.contact FROM job j , company c where c.id = j.company')->result_array();
```

I need the column company in the first query changes to be that

```
$job_query['company']=$companyC[key];
```

but I  a  get the key without loop of array_map

Comment: Do you want job_query's first record's company column data ?

Answer (score 1):

In codeigniter `result_array()` returns the all records in the form of array.So you have to use foreach loop for accessing columns.But if you want to only the first record then use `row_array()` as below:

```
$job_query = $this->db->query('SELECT * from job j , company c where j.company = c.id')->row_array();

  $companyC = $this->db->query('SELECT j.company ,c.title, c.city, c.logo , c.logo , c.contact FROM job j , company c where c.id = j.company')->row_array();
```

Then

```
$job_query['company'] = $companyC[key];
```

Answer (score 1):

yes i did that and it works the problem is that i had 2 queries but now i fixed it and  don't need the first i took the value from the second one any way thanks it helped.

foreach ($job_query as $key => $value) {
assigned a anew value here
$new = array();
}

Answer (score 0):

You can use **array_column** function for that

```
array_column($array, $columnname);
```

$array is the array you have

$columnname is the name of the key